# Using Rspec should receive

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am following a tutorial and have been getting some errors, I believe some of the language is outdated with Rspec and have messed around alot to try and fix this but have not been able to.

The error i get is

```
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `should_recieve' for #<Panda:0x007f9cd45c6458>
 # ./spec/zookeeper_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The code in question is

```
describe Zookeeper do 

it "should be able to feed the bamboo to the pandas" do 
    panda = Panda.new
    panda.should_recieve(:eat).with(:bamboo)
    Zookeeper.new.feed(food: :bamboo, to: panda)
end
```

Comment: yes i was trying to do that but i was initially trying to realise why the test was failing. it would seem my mis spelling to receive would be the problem!

Comment: what would be the appropriate alternative for should_receive as i believe this is deprecated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have realised that should_recieve should actually be should_receive and this has resolved the problem. I then replaced should_receive with and expectation and to receive

```
describe Zookeeper do 

    it "should be able to feed the bamboo to the pandas" do 
    panda = Panda.new
    expect(panda).to receive(:eat).with(:bamboo)
    Zookeeper.new.feed(food: :bamboo, to: panda)
end
```